# Increment digit by one Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to increment digit of the span by one every time i click on the button, if i click button 1 then span 1 should be incremented and so on ?

```
button 1: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-menu-btn"></a>
button 2: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-menu-btn"></a>
button 3: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-menu-btn"></a>
span 1: <span class="item-count">1</span>
span 2: <span class="item-count">1</span>
span 3: <span class="item-count">1</span>
```

Comment: What i've you tried with the jquery?

Comment: If you need a button please use a `<button>` not an anchor tag.

Comment: @Reyno anchor tags can be buttons as well

Comment: Anchor tags are not buttons. Sure, they can be made to look and behave like buttons, but they have different semantics. (Your use of `href="javascript:void(0)"` should be a hint to you that you're "doing it wrong".)

Comment: @Ouroborus what about this , is this button?)
<div class="MenuItemCard-7036f1acc28e0949" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="CHICKEN CAESAR SANDO MEAL"></div>

Comment: Almost. It's missing the actions that buttons imply. You'll note that there are distinct `role` options for each of `link` and `button`. Looking [deeper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/list_role), they have different functionality. While you can certainly make one element look and act like another, it raises the question: why not use the one built for the purpose?

Comment: @Andy, some systems are setup to dynamically create a generic parent object like a div then fill it with the rest of the elements and have the parent div accept the event handlers like a button. But those have very specific use cases as why they don't use traditional buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors are best for URLs and anchors (ie #pagesection). In this use case buttons are the better options.

In this answer, I give each button a data-target attribute. The value of this attribute is the ID of the element that you want to change.

I'm delegating the click handler to the body and just checking to see if what was clicked on was one of the buttons. Then I simply get the target span and its value and add 1.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
   let el = e.target;
   if(el.classList.contains("add-menu-btn")){
     let target = document.querySelector(el.dataset.target);
     target.innerText = Number(target.innerText) + 1
   }
});
```

```html
<button data-target="#span1" class="add-menu-btn">1</button>
<button data-target="#span2" class="add-menu-btn">2</button>
<button data-target="#span3" class="add-menu-btn">3</button>
<span id="span1" class="item-count">1</span>
<span id="span2" class="item-count">1</span>
<span id="span3" class="item-count">1</span>
```